# Matplotlib grid styles and titles not showing

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

After a lot of running around trying to get a matplotlib plot to show in a specific Tkinter frame, but the grid styles and titles aren't showing.  The plot creation is tied to a function which is tied to a button which works just fine.  The style works when the plot is charted on its own, or when plt.show() is called.  It also works when the whole thing is tied to a class and created that way.

Anybody have any idea why this isn't working?

```
def create_all_graph():
    recruiter = submit_entry.get()

    # Gather data for marketing calls
    rec_filter = df_tgr_year["recruiter"] == recruiter
    x_week = df_tgr_year.loc[rec_filter, ["week"]]

    # Marketing Calls
    mc_y_metric = df_tgr_year.loc[rec_filter, ["marketing_calls"]]

    # plot graph
    mc_figure = Figure(figsize=(4, 3), dpi=100)
    mc_plot = mc_figure.add_subplot(111)
    mc_plot.plot(x_week, mc_y_metric, color="#159cff", linewidth=2, marker='h', markerfacecolor="#FFFFFF",
                 markeredgewidth=2, markersize=5)

    mc_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(mc_figure, master=graph_frame)
    mc_canvas.draw()
    mc_canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=1, column=0)

    plt.ylim(ymin=0)
    plt.xlim(xmin=0)

    plt.title("Marketing Calls")
    plt.xlabel("Week")
    plt.ylabel("Marketing Calls")

    plt.minorticks_on()
    plt.grid(which="major", linestyle="-", linewidth="0.5", color="#d7eeff")
    plt.grid(which="minor", linestyle="-", linewidth="0.5", color="#d7eeff")

    plt.tight_layout()
```

There's something funny with triggering the code block for this question too but let's leave that for another time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [matplotlib docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/tutorials/introductory/lifecycle.html):

> Matplotlib has two interfaces. The first is an object-oriented (OO) interface. In this case, we utilize an instance of axes.Axes in order to render visualizations on an instance of figure.Figure.
>
> The second is based on MATLAB and uses a state-based interface. This is encapsulated in the pyplot module. See the pyplot tutorials for a more in-depth look at the pyplot interface.

Your diagram isn't displaying the labels and other styles, because you're plotting with the object-oriented interface and setting styles with the state-based interface. Switch everything to the object-oriented interface.

Here, I've switched your labels to the object-oriented interface and combined your code with [a tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html) to make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

```
import tkinter

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.axes import Axes


graph_frame = tkinter.Tk()
graph_frame.wm_title("Embedding in Tk")

x_week = [1, 2, 3]
mc_y_metric = [10, 20, 15]

# plot graph
mc_figure = Figure(figsize=(4, 3), dpi=100)
mc_plot: Axes = mc_figure.add_subplot(111)
mc_plot.plot(x_week, mc_y_metric, color="#159cff", linewidth=2, marker='h', markerfacecolor="#FFFFFF",
             markeredgewidth=2, markersize=5)

mc_plot.set_title("Marketing Calls")
mc_plot.set_xlabel("Week")
mc_plot.set_ylabel("Marketing Calls")

mc_figure.tight_layout()

mc_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(mc_figure, master=graph_frame)
mc_canvas.draw()
mc_canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=1, column=0)

tkinter.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you, for the helpful explanation and the example!  That worked, although I'm seeing issues stemming from me just not understanding how different module objects work together, but I'll have to research that on my own to get anywhere after all